# [SELECT with concat into %TYPE.]

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following case :

```
DECLARE v_var table_name.field%TYPE;
```

and something like SELECT field into v_var works.

But how could I handle this case with || (concatenate) :

```
SELECT field_1 || field_2 into v_var
```

What kind of %TYPE variable should I declare? Of table_name.field_1 or table_name of field_2? And what about the length of declared type in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a custom type of your specifications. In long packages this means more reusability if you have to extend the data type.

```
DECLARE
v_var  VARCHAR2(250);
SUBTYPE v_var_type IS v_var%type;

BEGIN

--do something

END;
```

This looks a little contrived but allows you to make the field larger at one point in the code rather than changing multiple hard coded declarations.

Even more elaborate usages are possible by creating a package of types. You can then reuse these throughout an application.

Comment: Ok, Thank you @kevinsky!